# How much long the key should be to create a secure encryption with One Time Pad?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

For example would a key with 15 random letters be enough to protect a 52 letters plain text?

Comment: Did you hear about the _perfect secrecy and C. Shannon_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a complete lack of even the most cursory research.

Answer (score 4):

This is well known. The pad must be made of uniformly chosen independent letters and be as long as the plaintext.